# my forms in my localhost on my PC work but on server does not work

Tags: php, mysqli, header

This is the login form, when i want to login it doesn't work but some days it works, first i used maysql function for connecting to data base and it shows http error

Comment: Please complete a basic, recent PHP+MySQL tutorial before you put anything online. You're not secured against sql injection at all and you don't even hash your users passwords. This is a dream for somebody who wants to steal data.

Comment: `mysqli_connect("localhost"` <-- are you **sure** your DB is on the localhost of your web server ?

Comment: yes These codes have worked well so far

Comment: I highly doubt that if you put this on a server you can create a database connection to `localhost`. At least on my site I had to put in the address of a database that was online.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please don't "blockquote" all of the text of your question.  Blockquotes serve they're own purpose.

Comment: @LLJ97 You often have to use localhost on servers, thats fine.

Comment: Okay, maybe I have just not ran into a situtation where I had to do that. My bad:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to connect "localhost" on your server. `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","example.com","password");`

You should re-write your connection line as;

```
$con = mysqli_connect('example.com', 'username', 'password', 'DatabaseName');
```

For some host servers, it can creates an error because of your hostname(example.com) if you get this error after re-write your connection code then please try to write your site's IP Address instead of it's name. Then It will work.

Comment: i try with my hostname and my site ip and delete if but it doesn't work and it goes on a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the error just by error reporting.
 Second 
you also need to define     die(); after mysqli query to show if their is problem in the query.

Sorry I can't paste code I am from mobile

Comment: i have used die but there is not any error , i say again this code have  worked fine

Comment: What it shows I mean error or what ? Is it showing page.php in header , and I am saying again put the error reporting E All code above the page.

Comment: i put error error_reporting(E_ALL); but there is no error

Comment: Seems like you are too new, Some times only error_reporting(E_ALL); not working, what if error reporting is not set from your configuration, So put ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL); as well on the top. And try try again